# Hibernate: Add a property in my class that is not mapped to a db-table

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-annotations

I have a table `tbl_sky` that has 2 properties `name` and `model` and I would use Hibernate annotation like;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_sky")
public class Sky implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String model;
    private String status;

    @Id
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
.
.
.
```

But I need to add one more property `status` that does not exist in the table but is needed in the class. How could I declare that property so that I have it in my class but not in my db-table?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: try  it without any annotations.

Comment: It maps it anyway as 'status'

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use `@Transient` annotation for field you are not going to store in DB:

```
@Transient
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

or:

```
@Transient
private String status;
```

Comment: it can go on the getter, or on the field itself.

Answer (score 13):

Mark it as `@Transient`, and it won't be part of the DB schema.

Answer (score 11):

If you annotate a field with `@Transient` it will not be persisted.